# Key Event happening twice when pressed with another key

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyevent, key-events

In my game, I use the event listeners `keyup` and `keydown` to track which keys are pressed (`this.input` is a reference to the `Input` function below):

```
$(document.body).on('keydown', this.input.keyPress.bind(this.input));
$(document.body).on('keyup', this.input.keyPress.bind(this.input));
```

Everything works as expected, until I press 2 keys at once. The left key moves the player left, the shift key fires a weapon. Separately, they work fine. If both are pressed at once, however, and held, the player shoots twice.

Here is the code I am using to handle the inputs (removed other key events for brevity)

`shootSpecial` should only be called once since `keyMap.shift` is only `true` on `keydown`. Once `keyup` is triggered, it is set to `false`:
`keyMap[key] = e.type === 'keydown';`

```
var Input = function () {
  var keyMap = {};

  this.handleKeyPress = function () {
    if (keyMap.arrowleft === true) {
      game.player.moving.left = true;
    } else if (keyMap.shift === true) {
      game.player.shootSpecial();
    }
  };

  this.keyPress = function (e) {
    var key = e.key.toLowerCase();
    if (key === ' ') {
      key = 'space';
    }
    keyMap[key] = e.type === 'keydown';
    console.log(key, keyMap[key]);
    this.handleKeyPress();
  };
};
```

The `console.log` reports that *left* and *shift* are `true` on `keydown` and then both `false` on `keyup` so I'm not too sure why it would be triggering the `shootSpecial` event twice.

```js
var keyMap = {};
var handleKeyPress = function () {
  if (keyMap.arrowleft === true) {
    console.log('left');
  } else if (keyMap.shift === true) {
    console.log('shift');  
  }
};

var keyPress = function (e) {
  var key = e.key.toLowerCase();
  keyMap[key] = e.type === 'keydown';
  if (document.getElementById(key))
    document.getElementById(key).innerText = e.type === 'keydown';
  
  handleKeyPress();
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyPress);
```

```html
LEFT:<div id="arrowleft">false</div>
SHIFT:<div id="shift">false</div>
```

As you can see by the fiddle, one event gets called twice.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to put up a snippet that demonstrates the error on jsfiddle? Then it would be much easier to track down your problem. Reading your code as you posted it makes it very hard to solve the issue, since it's obviously missing some logic (for example there's no code that sets keyMap values back to false when the key is released).

Comment: In the process of adding one now

Comment: It doesn't matter which key I use, the event is still triggered twice. (I thought maybe my shift key was a bit dodgy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you press two keys, you'll fire two events, whether you press them at the same time or not. The same for the `keyup` event. So in total the *handleKeypress* function is called four times.

The order might well happen to be:

```
key        | event   | keyMap.arrowleft | keyMap.shift | effect
-----------+---------+------------------+--------------+----------
shift      | keydown |     false        |     true     | shoot
arrowleft  | keydown |     true         |     true     | moving.left=true
arrowleft  | keyup   |     false        |     true     | shoot
shift      | keyup   |     false        |     false    | nothing
```

So in that scenario you shoot twice. Of course, this will not always be the case, as the order might be different.

#### Solution

Pass the key as argument to the *handleKeyPress* function to make sure you only execute an action that corresponds to that key.

```
var Input = function () {
  var keyMap = {};

  this.handleKeyPress = function (key) {
    switch (key) {
    case 'arrowleft':
      game.player.moving.left = keyMap[key]; // also sets back to false
      break;
    case 'shift':
      if (keyMap.shift) game.player.shootSpecial();
      break;
    }
  };

  this.keyPress = function (e) {
    var key = e.key.toLowerCase();
    if (key === ' ') {
      key = 'space';
    }
    keyMap[key] = e.type === 'keydown';
    this.handleKeyPress(key); // pass key
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're handling keydown and keyup with the same code, with the result that releasing key1 while pressing key2 has the same effect as pressing key2.

The fix is pretty easy: don't call your handleKeyPress function at all on keyup events.

```js
var keyMap = {};
var handleKeyPress = function () {
  if (keyMap.arrowleft === true) {
    console.log('left');
  } else if (keyMap.shift === true) {
    console.log('shift');  
  }
};

var keyPress = function (e) {
  var key = e.key.toLowerCase();
  keyMap[key] = e.type === 'keydown';
  if (document.getElementById(key))
    document.getElementById(key).innerText = e.type === 'keydown';
  
  // Only call handleKeyPress if the key is pressed
  if (keyMap[key]) {
    handleKeyPress();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyPress);
```

```html
LEFT:<div id="arrowleft">false</div>
SHIFT:<div id="shift">false</div>
```

---

Adding a suggestion in response to OP's comment. Your problem is that your handleKeyPress() has no information about whether the key was pressed down or up, and it also doesn't know which key was even pressed, only which keys are down at the time it is called. To get what you're aiming for, I would do something like this:

```js
var keyPress = function (e) {
  var key = e.key.toLowerCase(),
      isKeyDown = e.type === "keydown",
      output = key + (isKeyDown ? "-down" : "-up") + ": ";
  
  switch (key) {
    case "shift":
      if (isKeyDown) {
        output += "pew pew";
      } else {
        output += "doing nothing"
      }
      break;
      
    case "arrowleft":
      output += "updating walking_left";
      document.getElementById("walking_left").innerText = isKeyDown;
      break;
      
    default:
      output += "doing nothing";
  }

  console.log(output);
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyPress);
```

```html
Walking left:<div id="walking_left">false</div>
```

Comment: The problem with that is I still need to check for falsey values since this is what is used to tell the player to stop moving. If the value is true, move left, if not, stop moving left.

Comment: @CarlMarkham I've added a suggestion of how you could do what you're trying to get working that demonstrates that you need your logic to be able to respond to which key is being handled and whether it's been pressed down or up - there's no need to use a map of all keys' current states.